# Using wildcard in table data

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

Using MYSQL I have a table where the data has wildcards. Example...

```
|ID  | Model  |
|1   | dv209% |
```

I'm tryinh to write a sql query that will find row 1 when `model='dv209AWW'` or `model='dv209asdfs'`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `model` (with a value of either 'dv209AWW' or 'dv209asdfs') a field in another table, a variable or something else?

Comment: model is searched by a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
select id, model
from your_table
where 'dv209AWW' like model
order by id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, thought it's not what i need.
When building the query, I don't know 'dv209%' I only have the full model 'dv209aww'.

Comment: @user2220967 This should work... [see the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9709)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write that comment for the other post.

That's what my first attempt was, but I now found that there was some other error. Thank you this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Model
FROM yourTable
where model LIKE 'dv209%'
```

So it will find the row when the value is `dv209AWW` or `dv209asdfs`