# Querying a table that CONTAINS wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Short version:**

---

Basically I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689624/using-wildcard-in-table-data), but in excel.  Instead of querying a table USING wildcards, I want to query a table that CONTAINS wildcards.

**Long version:**

---

I'm creating a spreadsheet to summarize my bank account transactions at the end of each month.  I want to organise the transactions in my bank statement into categories like "groceries", "entertainment", "fuel" etc and then sum up the total amount spent on each category.

I have a sheet that acts as a database, with a list of known account names for each category (e.g. under "clothing" I have the names of the accounts of all the clothing stores I go to).  I then have another sheet with the first two columns containing transactions (account name, and amount), and then a column for each category.  I copy each amount in column 2 into the correct category column using the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($B2,database!B:B,0)),"",$C2)
```

Where column B is the "account name" column from my bank statement, and column C contains the amounts.

This works fine as long as the data in the database worksheet is an exact match.  But a lot of the account names are similar e.g. "7elevenl12345", "7eleven836549" etc.  How can I add strings with wildcards like "7eleven*" to my database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/wildcard-characters-HP005203612.aspx

Comment: Yes - I know how the wildcards work and how to use them in a formula directly.  Instead of using a wildcard in my formula, I want my formula to match a cell that contains a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SEARCH` for all the column B values in B2, although better to restrict the range so I'll use rows 2 to 100

`=IF(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$B2))),$C2,"")`

`SEARCH` automatically searches for a value **within** other text so no wildcards required [you should remove wildcards from the database you only need "7ELEVEN" etc.]. If one (or more) of the searches is a match then it will return a number and so will LOOKUP so you can test whether it does or not.

`SEARCH` function is not case-sensitive, change to `FIND` if you want the match to be case-sensitive

**Explanation:**

When you use

`=SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$B2)`

That returns an "array" the same size as Database!B$2:B$100. For each value in Database!B$2:B$100 you either get a number (if that specific value is found within B2 it's the position of the start of that value) or you get #VALUE! error.

Then when you lookup a "bignum" like 2^15 in that array, i.e.

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$B2))`

That returns the **last** number found in the array....or #N/A if there are no matches, so using ISNUMBER identifies whether there is at least one match or not.

If you want to see the whole array returned by

`=SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$B2)`

then put that in a cell and then select that cell, press F2 to select the formula and F9 to see the whole array.

If you have blanks in `Database!B$2:B$100` then that's a problem because a blank is always "found" in any value (at position 1) so you can edit the formula to prevent that, i.e.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$B2)*(Database!B$2:B$100<>""))),$C2,"")`

both versions of the formula can be shortened by using `COUNT` in place of `LOOKUP` and `ISNUMBER`, i.e. for that latter version you can use

`=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$B2)*(Database!B$2:B$100<>"")),$C2,"")`

but that version needs "array entry" - i.e. you need to confirm the formula with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> such that the formula is enclosed in curly braces like { and }

Note: 2^15 is used here because it is guaranteed to be a larger number than any number that SEARCH function can return. 2^15 = 32768 but the maximum number of characters in a cell is 1 fewer than that - 32767

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `=IF(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Database!B$2:B$100,$C2))),$C2,"")` instead? (the cell reference being $C2 instead of $B2 in the search).

Comment: @Jerry - No, I was trying to match the setup of Japes55 - he"s using B2 as lookup value....although perhaps that's not correct in retrospect

Comment: Oh, right, I just noticed that now. ^^; Though now, I'm a bit confused as to how his match could be working as intended for exact matches! Or maybe it was a typing error.

Comment: It works! thanks so much!
...but _how_ does it work?  If I paste just the SEARCH formula by itself in a cell, I get #VALUE errors? How am I able to pass a vector as the search term anyway?  Also there's one more slight problem: if I include blank cells in the range that makes the first argument of the SEARCH function, I always get a hit?

Comment: I can see that you used array as a first argument to search function but excel documentation on search function does not say you can use arrays there.

Answer (score 1):

You would to change your formula to: =IF(ISNA(MATCH($B2&"*",database!B:B,0)),"",$C2)

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this still uses wildcards in the query.
Row B contains elements like:
"7ELEVEN1234567"
"7ELEVEN8910111"

and my database has something like "7ELEVEN*"
So querying with e.g. "\*7ELEVEN1234567\*" still would not match.